# Главная страница в Open Server

Tags: html, menu, openserver, site

Есть сайт и **Open Server** я смог связать домен и свой IP в локальной сети,но к сожалению он открывает папку,а мне нужно что бы он открывал главную страницу,как сделать не подскажите?

Comment: А в папке в верхнем уровне есть какой-нибудь index.html или index.php? По идее если есть один из этих файлов, должен открывать автоматически...

Comment: @АлексейДрижаков В другой папке- localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По идее там должен располагаться один из этих файлов, тогда откроется автоматически. Если у Вас файл который открывает сайт называется по другому, то или:

1. Пропишите его в домене, чтобы адрес получился вроде myDomain/myMainFile.html;
2. Переименуйте файл, который у Вас открывает сайт как-то так:

Было: myMainFile.html, стало index.html. Само собой, если у Вас пути на этот файл с других файлов, их надо будет перепрописать.

Если файл, который открывает Ваш сайт находится во вложенной папке, то надо связать эту папку. Само собой во вложенной папке будут действовать те же условия, что прописаны в двух предыдущих пунктах.
Если localhost, то пропишите для этого сайта что-то типа localhost/folder/ 
Дело в том, что в папку localhost Вы можете добаить несколько разных папок с разными проектами, и если внутри папок будет один из index.html или index.php, то они будут открывать сайты с соответствующими папками.
localhost/mysite1;
localhost/mysite2;
localhost/mysite3;  и т.д.